Gallery with multiple Sort fields will not show any data
I have a gallery that is connected to SharePoint list, the gallery has the following formula for the items: -
Switch(DashBoarSortBy.Selected.Value,



"Network",
SortByColumns(Filter('Work Orders',
('Work Order Status'.Value = "Assigned" Or 'Work Order Status'.Value="New") And
((Created >= colSelectedDateCreated And Created <= colSelectedDateCreated2 ) Or IsBlank(colSelectedDateCreated)) And
(('Start Date.' >= colSelectedDateStartDate And 'Start Date.' <= colSelectedDateStartDate2  ) Or IsBlank(colSelectedDateStartDate)) And
(('End Date.' >= colSelectedDateEndDate And 'End Date.' < colSelectedDateEndDate2  ) Or IsBlank(colSelectedDateEndDate)) And
(Street = colSelectedStreetName Or IsBlank(colSelectedStreetName)) And
(Direction = colSelectedDirectionName Or IsBlank(colSelectedDirectionName)) And
('Location Name' = colSelectedLocationName Or IsBlank(colSelectedLocationName)) And
('Work Order Type'.Value = colSelectedTypeName Or IsBlank(colSelectedTypeName)) And
('Technician Name'.Email = colSelectedTechnicianName Or IsBlank(colSelectedTechnicianName) Or 'Work Order Type'.Value ="Posting"
Or 'Work Order Type'.Value ="UnPosting" Or 'Work Order Type'.Value ="Campaigns Photos" ) And
(Brand = colSelectedBrandName Or IsBlank(colSelectedBrandName)) And
('Work Order Status'.Value = colSelectedTStatusName Or IsBlank(colSelectedTStatusName))
),"NetworkName",SortOrder.Ascending,"SequenceNumber",SortOrder.Ascending),
"Created",
SortByColumns(Filter('Work Orders',
('Work Order Status'.Value = "Assigned" Or 'Work Order Status'.Value="New") And
((Created >= colSelectedDateCreated And Created <= colSelectedDateCreated2 ) Or IsBlank(colSelectedDateCreated)) And
(('Start Date.' >= colSelectedDateStartDate And 'Start Date.' <= colSelectedDateStartDate2  ) Or IsBlank(colSelectedDateStartDate)) And
(('End Date.' >= colSelectedDateEndDate And 'End Date.' < colSelectedDateEndDate2  ) Or IsBlank(colSelectedDateEndDate)) And
(Street = colSelectedStreetName Or IsBlank(colSelectedStreetName)) And
(Direction = colSelectedDirectionName Or IsBlank(colSelectedDirectionName)) And
('Location Name' = colSelectedLocationName Or IsBlank(colSelectedLocationName)) And
('Work Order Type'.Value = colSelectedTypeName Or IsBlank(colSelectedTypeName)) And
('Technician Name'.Email = colSelectedTechnicianName Or IsBlank(colSelectedTechnicianName) Or 'Work Order Type'.Value ="Posting"
Or 'Work Order Type'.Value ="UnPosting" Or 'Work Order Type'.Value ="Campaigns Photos" ) And
(Brand = colSelectedBrandName Or IsBlank(colSelectedBrandName)) And
('Work Order Status'.Value = colSelectedTStatusName Or IsBlank(colSelectedTStatusName))
),"Created",SortOrder.Descending),
"SequenceNumber",
SortByColumns(Filter('Work Orders',
('Work Order Status'.Value = "Assigned" Or 'Work Order Status'.Value="New") And
((Created >= colSelectedDateCreated And Created <= colSelectedDateCreated2 ) Or IsBlank(colSelectedDateCreated)) And
(('Start Date.' >= colSelectedDateStartDate And 'Start Date.' <= colSelectedDateStartDate2  ) Or IsBlank(colSelectedDateStartDate)) And
(('End Date.' >= colSelectedDateEndDate And 'End Date.' < colSelectedDateEndDate2  ) Or IsBlank(colSelectedDateEndDate)) And
(Street = colSelectedStreetName Or IsBlank(colSelectedStreetName)) And
(Direction = colSelectedDirectionName Or IsBlank(colSelectedDirectionName)) And
('Location Name' = colSelectedLocationName Or IsBlank(colSelectedLocationName)) And
('Work Order Type'.Value = colSelectedTypeName Or IsBlank(colSelectedTypeName)) And
('Technician Name'.Email = colSelectedTechnicianName Or IsBlank(colSelectedTechnicianName) Or 'Work Order Type'.Value ="Posting"
Or 'Work Order Type'.Value ="UnPosting" Or 'Work Order Type'.Value ="Campaigns Photos" ) And
(Brand = colSelectedBrandName Or IsBlank(colSelectedBrandName)) And
('Work Order Status'.Value = colSelectedTStatusName Or IsBlank(colSelectedTStatusName))
),"SequenceNumber",SortOrder.Ascending,"NetworkName",SortOrder.Ascending))

now the sort will only work if I select "Created", while SequenceNumber or "NetworkName" will not show any data.. this problem  start to happen when the "Work Order" list exceeds 5,000 items. although the Created + Sequenceumber + Networkame are added as indexes inside the list.. now if I remove the second sort field this will work for all the options.. so why I can not do multiple sorts for the gallery items, even if those fields are been indexed?
here are the indexes:-

Thanks

Although it's not directly related, it seems IsBlank() function is not a supported delegable to SharePoint. Could you replace it with Blank() and try it again?
For more info, please refer to MS Article
Also, at Power Apps SharePoint Delegation

IsBlank() will not be delegable if i am doing it against a sharepoint field ,, but in my case i am doing it against a variable , so it will be delegable ..

see the final answer in this thread https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Is-IsBlank-on-variables-have-any-delegation-problems/td-p/2240784
